# jQuery function returning [Object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery I'm attempting to retrieve the date from the first post and insert it into an `<h2>` right before the first `<article>`

jQuery:

```
(function(){
    var latestPost = $('.posts.new article').filter(':first');
    var postTime = latestPost.find('time').text();
    latestPost.before('<h2>' + postTime + '</h2>')
}());
```

HTML Before:

```
<div class="posts new">
    <article>
        <div class="title">First Post</div>
        <time datetime="2014-06-27">Today</time>
    </article>
    <article>
        <div class="title">Second Post</div>
        <time datetime="2014-06-26">Yesterday</time>
    </article>
 </div>
```

HTML After:

```
<div class="posts new">

    <h2>Today</h2>

    <article>
        <div class="title">First Post</div>
        <time datetime="2014-06-27">Today</time>
    </article>
    <article>
        <div class="title">Second Post</div>
        <time datetime="2014-06-26">Yesterday</time>
    </article>
 </div>
```

Right now, I can't seem to get this to work as intended. It's either showing `[Object Object]` or returning nothing altogether.

Am I going about this the wrong way / would there be a more efficient way of obtaining the first post's time and prepending it?

EDIT:

My code works, I'd just mistakenly placed it before a function it depended on.

Comment: what is problem with code in this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a45kQ/

Comment: what output u expect?

Comment: I doubt that `.text()` will ever return an object.

Comment: @PratikJoshi You're fiddle outputs exactly what I'm after, using my exact code example?! How strange. Thanks.

Comment: @FelixKling Why's that?

Comment: Because it's defined to return a string and if no elements had been selected, it probably returns `undefined`. Could it be that you are running the code before the DOM is ready?

Comment: Thanks for following up, I just started learning jQuery a few weeks ago so definitely still a beginner at it and making a lot of mistakes. My code is fine it was just the placement of it that was causing the issue. I had a function that generates the natural language post dates   running after this one. So at runtime `time` was empty... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running the js function immediately, you should run it on [document ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), i.e.:

```js
$(function(){
    var latestPost = $('.posts.new article').filter(':first');
    var postTime = latestPost.find('time').text();
    latestPost.before('<h2>' + postTime + '</h2>')
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/pry8p/